# How to find parent ZIP file from arguments when double-clicking in Windows Explorer - .NET 4.0

Tags: windows, vb.net, visual-studio

In [Windows Explorer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Explorer), when you open a ZIP file and double-click a file, say a JPEG file (.jpg), Windows extracts the JPEG file to a temporary folder, and passes the temporary file name to the associated program as the one and only argument, such as "C:\Users\jprice\AppData\Local\Temp\Temp1_<>.zip\<>.jpg"

I noticed that some applications, like the Windows Photo Viewer in Windows 7 know what ZIP file the temporary file came from. You can click next and previous and get the next/previous files from the ZIP file (as you do, they are also extracted to temporary files).

I've googled and prowled through `system.io.packaging`, but I can't figure out how to get the path of the original ZIP file (the file name is part of the temporary file path).
It's not done with the shell-->open command, Windows Photo Viewer only gets the temporary file name as far as I can tell.

The Photo Viewer command line is 
%SystemRoot%\System32\rundll32.exe "%ProgramFiles%\Windows Photo Viewer\PhotoViewer.dll", ImageView_Fullscreen %1
Which doesn't help.  I did use ProcessMon to watch Photo Viewer and saw it read the .zip file (probably using zipfldr.dll) but could not discover how it knew where the original zip file was.

Comment: Check the command-line used to start Photo Viewer in Process Explorer

Answer (score 1):

When I try it, I notice that WinZip initializes the spawned process's current working directory to the folder that the .zip resides in.  If you can extract the .zip filename from the temp file path (and older OS versions did not do that), then  you can reconstruct the original .zip file path.

Comment: Ideally I'd like to get it to work with the default file explorer. When opening a file inside a zip file using default file explorer, the current directory is (by Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() or System.Environment.CurrentDirectory() ) is always C:\windows\system32. If I open the file with 7Zip, the current directory is the temp directory. I didn't try with winzip, but I assume you are correct.

Comment: The zip app (whatever you decide to use) is the one launching the file, so it specifies the working directory for the new process, depending on which API it uses to open the file.